# How to only show a specific number of divs on the page and load more when the user scrolls to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 6 divs that all have the same class. How would I make it so that only the first 3 divs are shown on the page and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the other 3 divs are shown?

Also, there may not always be just 6 divs. Let's say there are 12 divs, the code will still need to show the first 3 divs and keep showing 3 more when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

```
<div class="post">
Lorem
</div>

<div class="post">
Lorem ipsum
</div>

<div class="post">
Lorem ipsum ....
</div>

<div class="post">
Lorem...
</div>

<div class="post">
Loremsdfdsf
</div>

<div class="post">
Lorem.......
</div>
```

I have only managed to find this http://jscroll.com/ but it requires you include a `href` link at the bottom of the page to the file that you would like to display when the user scrolls to the end.

Comment: Did you check out [Infinite Scroll](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/)?

Comment: Try to use iScroll.js..It will help you.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for providing a link to that but all it does it outline the pros and cons of using infinite scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery's convenient method scrollTop() and capture the scroll event with scroll(). You just check if the scroll was far enough and if yes - load the new content.

Comment: Thanks but that means showing one specific div when the user scrolls to a certain point of the page. There are multiple divs with the same class name - 3 has to be shown on the page and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, 3 more are loaded and that keeps on happening until all of the divs are shown

Comment: So just check in the scroll event capture callback, with $(window).scrollTop() and $(document).height(), whether the end of the document has been reached - if yes - load the 3 divs if there are any left to load.